# Is ‘smart alec (aleck)’ a gender-neutral noun?

Tags: meaning, gender-neutral

I happened to find the origin of the word, ‘smart alec (aleck / alick)’ as I was checking the spelling of the word in a dictionary.

Merriam Webster English Dictionary defines ‘smart alec (aleck / alick)’ as:

An obnoxiously conceited and self-assertive person with pretensions to smartness or cleverness.

And its origin as;

Aleck, nickname for Alexander

First Known Use: 1865.

Now that knowing ‘smart alec’ being a shortened form of ‘smart Alexander,’ I became a bit ill at ease, because I’ve used the word for both sex thus far without any reflection on its origin and gender.

Is there a female counterpart to smart alec? Is it alright to use ‘smart alec (aleck / alick)’ as usual for both a man and a woman?

Comment: In AmE, it's almost always 'smart aleck' (two words, lower case, '-ck'). There is no conscious connection to the name Alex or Alec, unless of course that is your own name and then it will be annoying.

Comment: There is a very nice name 'Alexandra' that you can remember while using the gender-neutral term 'smart alec' for a woman. Certain literary characters with that name were apparently strong and dominating women, tomboys and smart alecks, though I can't remember the details.

Comment: @Mitch I think the level of association between _smart-alec_ and the name will vary greatly. To me personally, it's a very obvious connection that I've always been aware of (like _billy-no-friends_ in Rory’s answer). I've always seen it as simply a name used in a generic fashion.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet While I'm at the opposite end of that: I had no idea "alec" was a name until I learned that Hardison's (from Leverage) first name was Alec

Comment: @NoName You’ve never heard of Alec Guinness (Obi-Wan Kenobi in the original _Star Wars_ movies) or Alec Baldwin?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not until after I watched Leverage. I don't read credits nearly as diligently as I probably should and I don't read tabloids - If I've watched something with either of those actors, I glossed over the name entirely. Also, not a fan of Star Wars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be used for either gender. A Smart Alec is a neutral noun - there is no gender attached or implied.

Additionally, as @TrevorD commented, Alec, Alex, and other similar contractions are used for female names as well as for male names.

Similarly, while the root of 'Billy No-Mates' is male, it can be used to describe an unpopular man or woman.

Comment: Good point Trevor